# Which is the proper algorithm to figure repeated substrings of longest total length?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, strings, substrings

Given a string $S$ and a substring $T$, define the value of $T$ to be the total length (in characters) of all non-overlapping instances of $T$ in $S$.  In other words, the value of $T$ is the length of $T$, times the number of times that $T$ occurs in $S$ without overlap.

I need an algorithm that does the following:

Given a string $S$, find the substring $T$ whose value is maximal, out of all substrings of length at least two; the index of each location where $T$ appears in $S$; and the value of $T$ (the total number of characters across all of those occurrences of $T$).

You can assume the string $S$ is ANSI encoded, where each character is one byte.

Example:

```
String => "AOOISDF000923RJJASPDFIJJ1023ASPD499FJJDSJIK"

Has the following repetitions:
1 - "DF", two times, total characters (4)
2 - "23", two times, total characters (4)
3 - "JJ", three times, total characters (6)
...
N - "ASPD", two times, total characters (8)
```

The desired output would be ASPD, because it has produced the largest total amount of characters (8).

Is there an efficient algorithm for this problem?  Is there a search term or name for this that I could use to search for it, or papers in the literature that describe techniques for this problem?

Comment: (I see 0 four times for a total of 4.) Look for ways to re-use results for simple versions of the problem (repeated characters, pairs, …) or try to find words for the essence of the problem or a solution you think possible (repetition), and look for approaches/algorithms/data structures.

Comment: (more than one character) For the problem this is (i believe) what I need, because there are no "words", only binary data.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the literature on the longest repeated substring problem, which is closely related but is trying to optimize a different metric.  There are many algorithms and techniques; it's possible some of them could be adjusted to apply to your problem.

For instance, one can find the optimum solution to your problem in $O(nr)$ time using [Rabin-Karp's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), where $r$ is the length of the longest repeated substring in $S$.  First, we compute $r$ using any standard method.  Then, for each $i$ in the range $1,2,\dots,r$, we look for the substring $T$ of length $i$ that is repeated the most number of times (without counting overlaps).  This can be done in $O(n)$ time for a fixed value of $i$, by using a [rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) to compute the hash of all length-$i$ substrings of $S$ and for each such length-$i$ substring, compute the number of times it is repeated (without counting overlaps).  This can be done using a hashtable and a greedy algorithm (each time you see a substring $T$, if it doesn't overlap with the last accepted occurrence of $T$, increment the count for $T$ and accept this occurrence, otherwise reject it).

For many distributions on input strings, $r$ is relatively small compared to $n$: e.g., $r = O(\lg n)$.  If that applies to your situation, then this Rabin-Karp-based method will be easy to implement and perform reasonably well.

You could also look at suffix trees or suffix arrays.  Each internal node in the suffix tree represents a candidate for the substring (a substring that occurs more than once in $S$).  However, it's not quite clear to me at the moment how to efficiently account for overlap according to your problem statement, so I don't have a specific algorithm to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You describe the first step of the "greedy off-line textual substitution" described in

- Alberto Apostolico, Stefano Lonardi: Off-Line Compression by Greedy Textual Substitution. Proc. IEEE, vol. 88 no. 11, pp. 1733-1744, Nov. 2000
- Alberto Apostolico, Stefano Lonardi: Some Theory and Practice of Greedy Off-Line Textual Substitution. Data Compression Conference 1998:119-128
- Alberto Apostolico, Stefano Lonardi: Compression of Biological Sequences by Greedy Off-Line Textual Substitution. Data Compression Conference 2000:143-152

Comment: That is a fun way to look at it.